# What is .config folder?

Tags: backup, configuration, directory

Inside I found configuration files for Deluge, which I needed to for a list of torrents. Does it contains all similar files?

If that so, can I just copy whole folder before reinstalling whole Ubuntu and then paste it back, preserving settings for programs?

Thank you.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312988/understanding-home-configuration-file-locations-config-and-local-sha

Answer (score 5):

In your home folder (`~` , usually `/home/<username>`) the `.config` folder has lots of config files for many programs (some use other "hidden dotfiles" that begin with a dot, like `.xxxx` folders or files, also in the home folder) and often the desktop / display manager settings too.

If you wanted to back up your whole home folder that would be a good idea too, and could later restore (copy/paste) it to retrieve it's saved settings. If you change user/usernames, then the owner of the files should match the current user.