# Create folders in root?

Tags: root

I am brand new to ubuntu and I am trying to create a new folder inside my `/` directory.

I have read many posts here that talk about giving myself ownership of files but when I try and do it with `/`, I get permission denied.

1. How do I freely create folders/files in root?
2. Can I make my user the root user?

**Question Clarification**

My question above is not clear because I didn't understand the scope of the Ubuntu file system.

I didn't want to create folders in root. **What I wanted to know is: Where is the best place to put my personal files (like my .dotfiles) in the Ubuntu file system.**

For newer Ubuntu/linux users like me, the comments below clarify the thinking with linux fliesystem.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? It is very, very rarely a good idea to create folders directly under `/` and an even worse idea to make your user the root user, especially if you are a new user. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you tell us why you want this, what your final objective is, we should be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but I am moving from mac Os and I had my .dotfiles folder in the root. 

Maybe there is a better place to put it? 

FYI - I have installed ubuntu on a i7 windows machine (duel boot).

Comment: Great insight on the XY problem. Noted for next time.

Comment: Oh wow yes. You absolutely do not want your dotfiles there, they should all be in your home directory. Basically, _never_ touch `/` unless you really know what you are doing. Everything that is only for your user should be in your `$HOME` and not in `/`.

Comment: Okay, so where would all my main config files be linked too? For example, I use Kitty terminal and kitty looks for the config file in .config/kitty. ?

Comment: I just realised that on ubuntu its the /home directory. Thanks Terdon

Comment: No, not the `/home` directory, it's the `/home/vinn` (or whatever your user name is) directory. That's where the programs you run will expect to find their configurations for your user. And you're welcome :)

Comment: Super helpful, could you add this as the answer? I think this would be helpful for new Ubuntu users :)

Comment: Eh, it isn't what the question is actually asking and we have several posts about the general idea. Have a look at [Why is there /etc and ~/.config? Why is the global config called "etc" yet the user's config stuff is called ".config"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1285152) and [What is .config folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/575035)

Comment: I suggest reading the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go.

Comment: @Vinn as it is now, your question is asking something different than what you want, so we can't post what you actually need to hear as an answer. You can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1407732/edit) your question to make it ask what you actually need (where to put config files which were in root in MacOS)

Comment: Thank you all. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply type in the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /root/<name_of_directory>
```

Here the command sudo is telling the system you want root privileges. Then enter your normal password or if you made a specific root password enter it.

The command mkdir will create a directory in the given PATH that is /root/<name_of_directory>

Comment: Did you read the comments on the original question? although this is what the question asks, this is not what the user needs, and is a VERY bad idea to do, especially for a new user.

Comment: @Esther i simply answered his question. He is free to do whatever he wants with this knowledge. Even though it's a bad idea, his question was clear. So was my answer.

Comment: The OP wanted to create the folder from /, not from /root.